# Problema con TransactionScope .Net SqlServer

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, transacciones

Habitualmente uso TransactionScope para mis desarrollos pero en este caso me encuentro con algo extraño. Tengo que actualizar en las tablas de Cabeceras de pedidos y de lineas de pedidos la fecha de entrega cuando el usuario haga una lectura del código de barras del documento en cuestión.

```
                Dim ts1 As New TimeSpan(0, Configuracion.TiempoTransaccion, 0)
                Dim Result As Boolean = True
                Using scope As New TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, ts1)
                    Using CnxWriter As New SqlConnection(CnxConnectionString)
                        Try
                            CnxWriter.Open()

                            ''9 - Actualizo la fecha de entrega del Documento Sage 
                            If F_DOCENTETE.Update_DO_DateLivr(Now, DO_Piece, eDO_type.Pedido, eDO_Domaine.Ventas, CnxWriter, Log) Then
                                addLog(String.Format("Actualizada la fecha de envio en el documento de Sage {0} referente al documento Web {1} por la impresora {2}.", DO_Piece, IdDocWeb, Configuracion.ImpresoraFacturaWeb), eT_TIpos.Ok, , Log)
                                If F_DOCLIGNE.Update_DO_DateLivr(Now, DO_Piece, eDO_type.Pedido, eDO_Domaine.Ventas, CnxWriter, Log) Then
                                    addLog(String.Format("Actualizada la fecha de envio en las lineas del documento de Sage {0} referente al documento Web {1} por la impresora {2}.", DO_Piece, IdDocWeb, Configuracion.ImpresoraFacturaWeb), eT_TIpos.Ok, , Log)
                                    If ADV_WSYNC_ESTADO_IMPRESION_ETQ_FAC.Update_UpdFchEntrega(IdDocWeb, True, CnxWriter, Log) Then
                                        Result = True
                                    Else
                                        Result = False
                                        addLog(String.Format("No se ha actualizado el check de Actualizada Fecha de Envio del documento de Sage {0} referente al documento Web {1}.", DO_Piece, IdDocWeb), eT_TIpos.Err, , Log)
                                    End If
                                Else
                                    ''La fecha de entrega no se actualiza correctamente en la cabecera del documento
                                    Result = False
                                    addLog(String.Format("No se ha actualizado la fecha de envio en las lineas del documento de Sage {0} referente al documento Web {1} por la impresora {2}.", DO_Piece, IdDocWeb, Configuracion.ImpresoraFacturaWeb), eT_TIpos.Warning, , Log)
                                End If
                            Else
                                ''La fecha de entrega no se actualiza correctamente en la cabecera del documento
                                Result = False
                                addLog(String.Format("No se ha actualizado la fecha de envio en el documento de Sage {0} referente al documento Web {1} por la impresora {2}.", DO_Piece, IdDocWeb, Configuracion.ImpresoraFacturaWeb), eT_TIpos.Warning, , Log)
                            End If


                            If Result Then
                                scope.Complete()
                            End If

                        Catch ex As Exception
                            ''Funciones.LanzarNotificador(ex.Message, eAccionNotificacion.Err)
                            addLog(ex.Message, eT_TIpos.Err, False, Log)
                        End Try
                    End Using
                End Using
```

Creo mi transacción con un tiempo de 5 minutos (Configurado por el usuario en Configuracion.TiempoTransaccion). Abro la conexión y hago tres actualizaciones. La primera `F_DOCENTETE.Update_DO_DateLivr` actualiza la fecha de entrega de la cabecera del pedido. A esta función le paso los datos de identificación única del registro y la conexión abierta con el transactionscope. Esta funciona perfectamente. La segunda `F_DOCLIGNE.Update_DO_DateLivr` actualiza la fecha de entrega en las lineas del pedido. A esta función le paso los datos de identificación del pedido (pueden ser varias lineas por pedido) y también la conexión abierta con el transactionscope. En esta función ya tengo el problema. El error me lo da la ejecución del comando por tiempo de espera aunque lo aumente a por ejemplo 10 minutos. Un update directamente sobre la tabla en Sql funciona perfectamente y usando la conexion a base de datos de la aplicación sin el transactionscope también funciona perfectamente. Ademas son funciones copiadas de otras funciones que uso diariamente. La única diferencia es la gran cantidad de registros que tiene la tabla de lineas de pedido.

He intentado hacerlo a piñon y tambien falla. La carga del DataTable funciona perfectamente. El Update falla.

```
                Dim ts1 As New TimeSpan(0, Configuracion.TiempoTransaccion, 0)
                Dim Result As Boolean = True
                Using scope As New TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, ts1)
                    Using CnxWriter As New SqlConnection(CnxConnectionString)
                        Try
                            CnxWriter.Open()

                    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DL_No FROM F_DOCLIGNE WHERE DO_Piece = 'pew079157' and DO_Type = 1 and DO_Domaine = 0", CnxWriter)
                                Dim tabla As New DataTable("Tabla")
                                da.Fill(tabla)

                                For Each _fila As DataRow In tabla.Rows
                                    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("UPDATE F_DOCLIGNE SET DO_DateLivr = '22/02/2017' WHERE DO_Piece = 'pew079157' and DO_Type = 1 and DO_Domaine = 0 and dl_no = " + _fila(0).ToString, CnxWriter)
                                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 60
                                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                                Next

                                scope.Complete()

                        Catch ex As Exception
                            ''Funciones.LanzarNotificador(ex.Message, eAccionNotificacion.Err)
                            addLog(ex.Message, eT_TIpos.Err, False, Log)
                        End Try
                    End Using
                End Using
```

Comment: Has mirado si podría ser algo relacionado con la base de datos? No se, un tema de actualización de índices quizás? Podrías probar a lanzar la sql que te da error a mano sobre la tabla de producción y probar?

Comment: Sobre la tabla directamente funciona perfectamente y se ejecuta en menos de 1 segundo. Estoy probando con SqlTransaction y también funciona. Lo mas curioso es que sobre otras tablas si funciona dentro de la misma transaccion.

Comment: Tu segundo fragmento de codigo tiene algo que puede hacer que tarde mucho, y es que estas haciendo un update por cada fila de la tabla. No se si tu función `F_DOCENTETE.Update_DO_DateLivr` hace lo mismo, pero eso si hay muchas filas puede hacer que efectivamente te de un timeout

Comment: El segundo fragmento de código es una prueba desesperada para lanzar un update mas fino. Ambos dan problema. El bueno es el primero. En el segundo lo que hago es añadir un campo mas en la condición de búsqueda del registro para que solo se actualice un registro cada vez pero en la primera pasada ya se queda enganchado.

Comment: Deduzco entonces que en tu codigo bueno utilizas DataAdapter.Update no? Has probado a reiniciar tu servidor de base de datos por si se hubiera producido algun bloqueo en alguna fila que este impidiendo el update?

Comment: No. El dataadapter ha sido una prueba. El código bueno es el primero donde llamo por ejemplo a la función F_DOCLIGNE.Update_DO_DateLivr. Dentro lo que hago es montar con parámetros mi sqlcommand. ¿Si hubiera un bloqueo en alguna fila no podría tampoco lanzar el update directamente a la tabla con el Management Studio de Sql Server no? Igual voy a probar.